# Will this inverted switching circuit to drive 4 Ohm heater work?

Tags: circuit-design, switching, load

I want to switch a heater, and learn to build some electronics while doing so). The heater is a heated print bed, from the Ultimaker original heated print bed kit (no longer sold I think). The problem is that the PSU that comes with the printer is underrated to provide the current. I've got a spare PSU that I wish to add to power the bed.

The original signal to drive the heater is 24vdc high when the heater is off, and 0Vdc when the heater is on. I hope to be able to drive it using the circuit below. The heaters resistance is 4 ohm, displayed as R5. Q1 ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/BS270-1006630.pdf)) is ment to invert the signal, so Q2 ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/196/IPP075N15N3%20G_Rev2.03-96996.pdf)) should be on when the original signal is low (coming from the 24Vdc + pin in the circuit). Q1 and Q2 are both N-channel MOSFETs.

I'm far from experienced with electronics. I hope that someone will shed some light on whether this will work, and if not, what I should correct. And of course, why it should be corrected, because the learning is an important aspect of doing this for me.

And of course, if there is something wrong with the drawing. Like unusual choice of components or symbols, I like to hear that to.

Will this circuit work to drive the heater?

[image: Circuit to drive heater]

**EDIT**

As Chris Stratton pointed out, there are test points on the circuit that is driving the heater, as shown [here](https://github.com/Ultimaker/HeatedBedUpgrade/blob/master/1527%20Heated%20Bed%20PCB/electronics/Heaterboard%20V1.1%20Schematic.PDF) (or in the image below).

[image]

TP15 shows 8.2volts, steady line (measured with oscilloscope), when the heater is powered, and 0 when it is not. The 075N15N MOSFET shows the following figure, which seems an acceptable RdsOn with 8.2v on the gate. I do not understand why it is 8.2v and not the seemingly more optimal 10v as it is seems to me to be simply a matter of picking different resistors for the voltage divider R29/R30. I did not dare to put the probe on pin 4 of Q2. But I assume the voltage is probably the same there. Anyway, I can use the signal coming from TP15 to switch a low side N-channel MOSFET to drive the heater using an external PSU that shares GND.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you have two voltage sources? One at \$24\:\textrm{V}\$ used for signalling only and another at \$19.6\:\textrm{V}\$ for power delivery to the heated print bed?

Comment: @jonk Its for a printer. But duak extrusion, using two print heads, and a heated bed, all powered on, draws too much current. I cant find a suitable PSU to heat all at once. Therefore I hope to use a second PSU indeed and share their GND.

Comment: Regarding the text on the drawing, you really should write (24V/10k+10k) as 24V / (10k + 10k) as the former is meaningless. And there ought to be a space between the number and the unit of a quantity, strictly speaking.

Comment: You may want to use a current limiting version of this. Just to keep the current below a max threshold. (I have two 3D printers here, both already with heated platforms, and am configuring them for multi-zone heating in order to deal with the edge effects of the platform.) But if you want to run a regulated voltage, that's fine with me.

Comment: @Andrew thanks. I see what you mean. I will when I am begind my pc this evening later in.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Also, your BS270 can't tolerate \$24\:\textrm{V}\$ on its gate. I know you have a divider there to cut it in half, but if \$R_2\$ fails for any reason, or is loose, then ...

Comment: @jonk. I noticed the effect of the edge to indeed. I never print big parts so never had problems with it. 3 printers is alot! Which ine you have? Ive got an Ultimaker original. What do you mean with regulated voltage? The difference between 19.6Vdc PDu and 24Vdc just happens to be because I have a spare 19.6Vdc notebook charger which can handle the current for the heater.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about a certain level of failing components safety or what isnthe official term for that, if any? I heard once that some electronics have mandatory design specs for failing components indeed. What do you recommend? Or can you point me to some literature online?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Yeah. That's an answer. I have the original Thing-O-Matic, v7 (bought as a kit for my son to assemble and learn from) and a Replicator 2X Experimental 3D Printer (2 head) that was bought assembled. Love both of them. Got it about the notebook charger -- it's not fantastic. But if it is what you have....

Comment: First thing you need to do is look at the schematic of *your* printer, or a similar one.  Chances are the "signal" you refer to is actually the output of the existing driver, which is probably a MOSFET low side switch, so effectively an open-drain output.  While you could *load that* with a suitable resistor and derive a signal, you might just grab the existing gate drive signal.  Or, if the existing circuit is as simple as it often is, you could probably just tie your supply grounds together, connect the high side of the heated bed to the new supply **and use the existing low side switch**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You seem to be in the correct direction. It is a N MOSFET indeed. I thiught about soldering a wire on the Gate of the original circuit, but I am reallly not experienced and a bit worried I will wreck something instead. Just hooking up the PSU with shared GND would be great because of the simplicity! Thanks for your comment. I will investigate further.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is the schema https://github.com/Ultimaker/HeatedBedUpgrade/blob/master/1527%20Heated%20Bed%20PCB/electronics/Heaterboard%20V1.1%20Schematic.PDF?raw=true J5 on the right is the heated bed. Do you thunk I can replace that 24vdc with another PSU when GND is shared? I think so. Would be nice!

Comment: That diode makes things complicated and introduces relative voltage and power sequencing issues.  Notice that the gate drive signal is available on a test point.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hmm yes indeed like ~6V would flow towards the 19.6v PSU. Aha, the test points. I never been aware of those before. They are on the bottom side of the PCB as well I think. Those are easier to solder than a pin on a SO-8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the diode build in Q1. It is forward polarized, so max voltage on Q2 will be too low to switch on Q2, and doesn't matter what would you do on G of Q1.
EDIT:
User Andrew Morton pointed that BS270N is a N-ch FET, so it's just a matter of schematic symbol used by OP. If this is corrected, then yes, the circuit will do its work. (Sorry for nasty schematic edit...)

[image]

Comment: OP chose the wrong symbol: a BS270 is an N-channel device.

Comment: Yes indeed... I copied it from BS250 because BS270 wasn't in the library. I forget to check whether BS250 was N-channel... (shame...) Thanks for pointing it out.